# find dynamic added panel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, panel

i'm adding a panel like this to my web application:

```
For i = 1 To amountOfRechnungspositionen + 1 
  Dim pnlPositon As Panel = New Panel
  pnlPositon.ID = "pnlPositon" & i
  pnlRechungsposition.Controls.Add(pnlPositon)
   ... 
Next
```

Now if i onclick a button, i want to delete this panel.
This is my code.

```
Private Sub imgDelRechnungsPosition_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles imgDelRechnungsPosition.Click

    amountOfRechnungspositionen = Convert.ToInt32(hfAmountofRechnungspositionen.Value)

    Dim fcpnlPositon As Panel = DirectCast(pnlRechungsposition.FindControl("placeholderID$pnlPositon" + amountOfRechnungspositionen.ToString()), Panel)
    fcpnlPositon.Dispose()

    hfAmountofRechnungspositionen.Value = Convert.ToString(amountOfRechnungspositionen - 1)

End Sub
```

But fcpnlPositon is Nothing.
Waht i'm doing wrong?

Thank u, for reading.

Comment: Are you adding the Panel on every postback? Remember dynamic controls will be lost after every _postback_

Comment: On postback i'm doing this: If Not IsPostBack Then genNeueRechnungsPosition() End If EDIT: Oh sry the function genNeueRechnungsPosition is the function which added the panel

Comment: What is `genNeueRechnungsPosition`? Probably method to add Panel dynamically? So yes you are not adding them on every postback right?

Comment: Yes i'm not adding them on every postback. Sry i hit enter and wasn't ready typing

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
CType(pnlRechungsposition.FindControl("pnlPositon" + 
           amountOfRechnungspositionen.ToString()), Panel)
```

The placeholder text is only for client-side markup and thus you want to use the direct ID property.

Comment: You are rebuilding the list of panels on page init every time, correct?  What is pnlRechungsposition.Controls.Count property return from within the button click.